Simple relationship between correlations
The following question rose from work with time-series but I generalized it so that it might be interesting to a larger audience:

Let A, C be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and B,D vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Suppose that
$\quad 
\operatorname{corr}(A, C) = a\quad
\mbox{and}\quad
\operatorname{corr}(B, D) = b
$.
The following relationship seems intuitive :
$$
\min(a, b) \leq \operatorname{corr}\left(\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} C \\ D \end{bmatrix}\right) \leq \max(a, b)
$$

But the proof isn't as straightforward as I thought it would be and can't be found in literature.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hi Mathis: If you have two vectors of the same dimension, $m$, and you want their correlation ( or covariance ), then the result has to be an $m \times m$ matrix. So, corr(B.D) can't equal b. I could be mis-understanding your notation ?

@markleeds I believe OP means a sample correlation.

kurt: If that was the case, it would mean that the vectors were occurrences of iid sample observations which was not stated. Usually sample observations are stated as sample observations. But you may be correct. Mathis is the only person that can straighten that out.

This is wrong.
I will write $A\&C=\pmatrix{A\\C}$ and so on.
$$
A={1\choose -1}\,,\quad C={1\choose -1}\,,\quad B={1\choose -1}\,,\quad D={0.1\choose -0.1} 
$$
$$
\operatorname{corr}(A,C)=1\,,\quad\operatorname{corr}(B,D)=1
$$
$$
\operatorname{var}(A\&B)=1\,,\quad \operatorname{var}(C\&D)=\frac{1+1+0.01+0.01}4=0.505\,,
$$
$$
\quad\operatorname{corr}(A\&B,C\&D)=\frac{(1+1+0.1+0.1)/4}{\sqrt{0.505}}\approx \color{red}{0.774\not\in[1,1]}\,.
$$
